# Recognize specific keywords in background mode

Tags: ios, iphone, background

I have a scenario in app,
Basically it is an Emergency app. In which user can set some specific keywords, and in case of emergency when user repeat these keywords the app should have to perform specific function.

We are stuck when user is in background mode, is there any why to recognize keywords in background mode.

please refer any idea to complete this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's not a bad idea, but I'm afraid there is no way on iOS to do this. I think Emergency SOS works better (think about how critical could it be if the words spoken are not recognized correctly by the app).

Comment: is there no any possibility?

Comment: maybe some other background service make it easy, one of my friend said i can run silent music in background,

Comment: is there any way?